# Como que eu pego o número de top que minha animação está no momento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma animação em JavaScript que vai do `top: 0px` no CSS e por jQuery *animation* ele vai até o `top: 385px` que é onde termina a animação.

Gostaria de saber como que eu pego o número que ele está atualmente no `top` antes de chegar ao fim?

Código:

```
$(function() {
$(".cair").animate({
  top:"+=385px",
},{
  duration: 6000,
  "complete" : function() {
  $('.cair').remove();
}
});
});

css:
.cair{
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Você quer essa informação durante a execução da animação?

Comment: Sim, durante a animação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `.animate()` tem uma função [**progress**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) que pode ser chamada para isto que pretende:

```
$(function () {
    $(".cair").animate({
        top: "+=385px",
    }, {
        duration: 6000,
            "complete": function () {
            $('.cair').remove();
        },
        progress: function (a, p, r) {
            //usar como quiser aqui
        }
    });
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tL7Dm/

Segundo a documentação, a função progress têm 3 parâmetros. O segundo passa a percentagem em que a animação está. O terceiro o numero de milisegundos que faltam até a animação acabar. Esta função foi adicionada na versão 1.8

**Para obter a posição do top tem duas maneiras:**

- ler a cada passo a posição/css `top`

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/hxx39/1/

```
    progress: function (a, p, r) {
        console.log(this.style.top);
    }
```

- usar a percentagem para fazer as contas de "onde é esperado estar"

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/hxx39/

```
    progress: function (a, p, r) {
        var valorAtual = p * (fim - inicio);
        if (Math.round(valorAtual) == 200) alert('chegámos aos 200px!');
    }
```